# How to get values exclusively in sql?

Tags: mysql

So I was writing a sql code getting players that is only in team 2:

```
SELECT PlayerID from Player 
WHERE EXISTS 
( SELECT * from Team WHERE team.PlayerID = Player.PlayerID  AND Team.TeamID = 't002');
```

The problem is, I forgot that there might be cases a player is also in other teams so any ideas how to fix that?

Comment: so your team table contains rows that have playerId AND teamId as the key?

Comment: If you like, consider following this simple two-step course of action:1. If you have not already done so, provide proper CREATE and INSERT statements (and/or an sqlfiddle) so that we can more easily replicate the problem. 2. If you have not already done so, provide a desired result set that corresponds with the information provided in step 1.

Answer (score 1):

Use in and not in

```
SELECT PlayerID from Player 
WHERE PlayerID in ( 
        SELECT  team.PlayerID from Team WHERE  Team.TeamID = 't002'
)
AND not in (
       SELECT  team.PlayerID from Team WHERE  Team.TeamID != 't002'
)
;
```

Answer (score 0):

Should use join instead

```
SELECT PlayerId FROM Player JOIN Team 
WHERE Team.PlayerId = Player.PlayerId AND Team.TeamId = 't002' 
AND NOT IN (SELECT team.PlayerID FROM Team 
WHERE Team.TeamId != 't002' );
```